# Error Supplied function does not return a valid float

Tags: python

I checked the functions and parameters but i can't find my mistake. Please comment if you know what's going on here.

Here is my code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad
from sympy.mpmath import sin, cos, sqrt, pi


k0=0.1

def f(y, k):
    return  k**2 + (1 - k**2)*y**2

def p1(y,k):
    return (1/f(y,k))*(f(y,k) - k**2 + (k**2)*sin(2*pi*sqrt(f(y,k)))/(2*pi*sqrt(f(y,k))))

def p2(y,k):
    return (-1*k/(sqrt(1-y**2)*2*pi*f(y,k)))*(1 - cos(2*pi*sqrt(f(y,k)) ))

def p3(y,k):
   return (k*y/(f(y,k)*sqrt(1-y**2)))*(f(y,k) - 1 + sin(2*pi*sqrt(f(y,k)))/(2*pi*sqrt(f(y,k))))

def q1(y,k):
   return k*(1- y**2)*(1 - cos(2*pi*sqrt(f(y,k))))/f(y,k)

def q2(y,k):
   return sqrt(1- y**2)*sin(2*pi*sqrt(f(y,k)))/sqrt(f(y,k))

def q3(y,k):
    return y*sqrt(1-y**2)*(1 - cos(2*pi*sqrt(f(y,k))))/f(y,k)

r1 = lambda k: dblquad( lambda y,x: p2(x,k)*q3(y,k) - p3(x,k)*q2(y,k), -1, 1, lambda y: -1 , lambda y: y  )

b = quad(r1, k0, 1)

print (b)
```

Comment: What line is erroring?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? Can you post the complete error you're getting?

Comment: python 3. retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_outputepsabs, epsrel, limit, points) line 281
return_quad_quadpack_qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output_epsabs,epsrel,limit) line 345

Answer (score 1):

It might be because `dblquad()` returns a tuple (y, error), so you need to index into the tuple to extract the float:

```
r1 = lambda k: dblquad(lambda y, x: p2(x,k)*q3(y,k) - p3(x,k)*q2(y,k),
                       -1, 1, lambda y: -1, lambda y: y)[0]
b = quad(r1, k0, 1)
print(b)
#Output: (0.2802359612009363, 4.646614072058449e-15)
```

Comment: your code take a long time to run? It's appear here a msg:the integral is probably divergent or slwoly convergent.

Comment: Yes it took a while to run.

Comment: has over 50 minutes, it's running yet

Comment: it took about 10 mins.